# What is the volume of $SO(n)$?

Tags: lie-groups

Per title ...

There's a question about this on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-volume-of-math-SO-n-math), but unfortunately both proofs are way over my head, and the answers differ as well - working through the expression in the second answer gives the volume of $SO(3)$ as $8\pi^2$, which is different from $2^{9/2} \pi^2$ as in the first answer.

Proposition 2.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0808.pdf) gives an expression for the volume of $SO(n)$ as well, but unfortunately it's also beyond my level of understanding.

Comment: You have to specify what metric you're putting on $\text{SO}(n)$.  It's kind of like asking, "What is the volume of a sphere?"  It depends: Do you mean the sphere of radius $1$ or the sphere of radius $17$ or ....?

Comment: Indeed it should be specified. The Killing form provides a natural normalization. Sometimes one requires that the max of the sectional curvature is $+1$, which yields another normalization.

Comment: @JesseMadnick hmm I don't know what the metric is for my application, but I do know the result I expect for SO(3). Does this mean I can safely use the answer on Quora that gives that result and extent to SO(n)?